# javascript limit to if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, limit

I got this problem with my code, if you place 4 diagonal in a row from left to right and from bottom to top it doesn't say that someone won (the 4th else if statement). It is programmed that every time you put a coin on the field it checkers if there are any 3 in a row around it, if so it says that you won. And it works fine, till the 4th else if-statement, also nextTurn(); won't work (like everything I put under the 4th else if-statement). Also after a while (halfway or so) it just totally stop working.

```
function testForWin(y,x) {
    if ((board[y][x+1] == p && board[y][x+2] == p && board[y][x+3] == p) || 
        (board[y][x-1] == p && board[y][x+1] == p && board[y][x+2] == p) || 
        (board[y][x-2] == p && board[y][x-1] == p && board[y][x+1] == p) || 
        (board[y][x-3] == p && board[y][x-2] == p && board[y][x-1] == p)) {
        win();
    }
    else if (board[y+1][x] == p && board[y+2][x] == p && board[y+3][x] == p) {
        win();
    } 
    else if ((board[y+1][x-1] == p && board[y+2][x-2] == p && board[y+3][x-3] == p) ||  
             (board[y-1][x+1] == p && board[y+1][x-1] == p && board[y+2][x-2] == p) ||
             (board[y-2][x+2] == p && board[y-1][x+1] == p && board[y+1][x-1] == p) || 
             (board[y-3][x+3] == p && board[y-2][x+2] == p && board[y-1][x+1] == p)) {
        win();
    }
    else if ((board[y+1][x+1] == p && board[y+2][x+2] == p && board[y+3][x+3] == p) ||
             (board[y-1][x-1] == p && board[y+1][x+1] == p && board[y+2][x+2] == p) || 
             (board[y-2][x-2] == p && board[y-1][x-1] == p && board[y+1][x+1] == p) || 
             (board[y-3][x-3] == p && board[y-2][x-2] == p && board[y-1][x-1] == p)) {
        win();
    }

    nextTurn();
}
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, might be able to skip all those ifs

Comment: This question is surely not about coding, but about logic. Even if there was a limit on the number of `else ifs`, this code would be far away from it. Did you try debugging it? I'm not familiar with the _connect 4 game_, and I'm pretty sure if you could explain what exactly you're trying to achieve it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Maybe you should not invoke the nextTurn() after a win(). I would suggest to do some refactoring. testForWin should return boolean. Then the method does what it says it does. Then depending on the return value, the win() can be invoked or nextTurn can be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank hou all for sharing your thoughts, but I fixed it myself after spending another 2 hours on it. :)